# Disable the button after clicking the button once

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my application i need to disable the button once it is clicked so that user should not click more than once. APplication is MVC ASP.NET i have done this in normal asp.net application. 
I tried below lines of code but its not working

thanks in Advance

**edited**
How can i implement this using javascript ?

Comment: You seem to have poor understanding of asp.net mvc. Check out some of the videos at http://www.asp.net/(S(pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3))/learn/mvc/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable submit button once it has been clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked)

Answer (score 7):

I've found that with IE8 (I'm not sure about other versions of IE) that you cannot submit a form if you disable the button on the click event. So I came up with an alternate solution. Hide the clicked button and put a new disabled button in it's place. Here's the code:

```
$().ready(function() {
  $("someButtonSelector").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).after('<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="' + $(this).val() + '" />');
    return true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
onclick="if (this.getAttribute('clicked') == '1') { return false; } else { this.setAttribute('clicked', '1'); }"
```

It will not disable anything, just prevent the click event after being first clicked.

Comment: +1 for a great -- and underrated -- solution.  IMO, you don't need to actually see the button's disabled style.  Let the user click rapidly as many times as they want.  All the dev cares about is avoiding duplicate posts.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.disabled = 'disabled';">Click Me!</button>
```

Although the Button web control renders as a submit:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = 'disabled';" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: sorry but it wont work in MVC application. you can do it in ASP.NET application but not in MVC

Comment: @prakash: Both of these methods will work, regardless of ASP.NET or ASP.NET-MVC. Can you post what you've tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

@prakash have you used jQuery to disable or even hide the button?

If your button's id is say "btnClickMe" then the following jQuery will do the job.

```
$("#btnClickMe").hide();
```

You could also set the disbaled attribute using jQuery;

```
$("#btnClickMe").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

The one above is untested but should work.

Comment: Nup its not working .. its disabling the button but form is not submitting

Answer (score 0):

i have found that if you disable or even remove the button or input element it will stop the call back to the server the most simplest way to handle this is a hide() because you are not removing the functionality of the input button/whatever

```
    $('input_selector').click(function () {
      $(this).hide(200/whatever);
      $(this).before('<p>Waiting for server to respond?!?</p><br/>')
    });
```

since it is a hide the br is to make sure the p tag is on top of it.
there may be a better way and i am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine as well, and it's easy to understand:

```
var myButton = $('input:submit');
var waitMessage = 'wait please...';
myButton.click(function() {
    if (bottone.val() == waitMessage) {
        return false;
    };
    myButton.val(waitMessage);
    console.log('iClicked'); // this line is for testing only, it can be removed.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my buttons that calls an MVC action then disables itself:

```
<button  class="btn blue pull-right" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "GetData", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = Model.CurrentSort, fromDate = Model.FromDateParam, toDate = Model.ToDateParam, terminatingpoint = Model.TerminationPointParam, SurecallNo = Model.SurecallNoParm, CallerID = Model.CallerIDParm, outcome = Model.OutcomeParm, pagesize = Model.PageSize })';this.disabled = 'disabled'" >Next ></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var but = 1;
function f() {
    if(but == 1) {
        alert("Hello World!");
        but = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
OnClientClick="if (this.getAttribute('clicked') == '1') {
    return false; 
} else { 
    this.setAttribute('clicked', '1'); 
}"
```