# Disable ASP.NET Forms button after click to prevent double clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET button that I need to disable after the user clicks it to prevent double-clicking.  Once the submit completes it has to be enabled again. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It's simple button.enable = false after your desired code completion

Comment: Is this a normal postback or AJAX?

Comment: See my answer for another question if you don't want to fix this on a button-by-button basis: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28844217/787757

Answer (score 48):

Here is a solution that works for the asp.net button object. On the front end, add these attributes to your asp:Button definition:

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

In the back end, in the click event handler method call, add this code to the end (preferably in a finally block)

```
myButton.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: day 1 with asp.net, my button gets disabled but never gets enabled again, what could I be missing

Comment: It does not work. My button is still enabled and I can click on it again while it is still processing the response.

Answer (score 37):

I have found [this](http://tgynther.blogspot.com/2011/07/aspnet-prevent-button-double-click.html), and it works:

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add(
    "onclick", 
    "this.disabled = true;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, null) + ";");
```

Comment: What's clientScript ?

Comment: i believe they're referring to Page.ClientScript (in System.Web.UI namespace)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808329/the-name-clientscript-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score 17):

Check this link, the most simplest way and it does not disable the validations.

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Button-before-Page-PostBack-in-ASP.Net.aspx

If you have e.g.

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
  </form>
```

Then you can use

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function DisableButton() {
      document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
  }
  window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;
  </script>
```

To disable the button *if* and *after* validation has succeeded, just as the page is doing a server postback.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work. The button is still enabled while waiting for the post to complete (meaning you can click on it many times).

Comment: Excellent solution!, it's working perfectly for me thanks!!.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to prevent double clicking due to a slow responding server side code then this works fine:

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Try putting a Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) on the _Click() event on the server and you will see the button is disabled for the time that the server is processing the click event.

No need for server side code to re-enable the button either!

You can also change button text, as suggested in  [How to disable submit button once it has been clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked)

```
   this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…';
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for what I needed to accomplish.  You can also add `this.style.backgroundcolor = '#abcdef';` to change style aspects of the element.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just want to emphasize the need for `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`, without that, your button click will not fire in code-behind.

Comment: @ShawnGavett where do you exactly add that line?

Comment: @Zizzipupp - you can create a CSS class and apply it to the `CssClass` attribute on the button, or you can do an inline style with the `Style` attribute.

Answer (score 11):

Just need to add 2 attributes for asp button :

```
OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';"  UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

e.g.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="TEST" OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="button-content btnwidth" OnClick="ServerSideMethod_Click"  />
```

For more details:

https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/918280-disable-button-click-prevent-multiple-postbacks

Answer (score 10):

If anyone cares I found this post initially, but I use ASP.NET's build in Validation on the page.  The solutions work, but disable the button even if its been validated.  You can use this following code in order to make it so it only disables the button if it passes page validation.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" OnClientClick=" if ( Page_ClientValidate() ) { this.value='Submitting..'; this.disabled=true; }" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Comment: This is the only answer I could find that actually works! Even better, the button changes to let the user know it's being submitted (no giant DIV overlays or other nonsense!)

Answer (score 5):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClick="Button_Click"/>
```

---

```
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function DisableButton()
            {
                document.getElementById("<%=btnSend.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
            }
            window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the client-side [onclick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx) event to do that:

```
yourButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable the button on the OnClick event, then re-enable on the AJAX callback event handler.  Here is how I do it with jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#buttonId').click(function() {
         $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         callAjax();
    });

});

function callAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/test.html',
      success: function(data) {
         //enable button
         $('#buttonId').removeAttr('disabled');

      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: And where do you put this code? If it is a standalone script, how do you call it from the c# code-behind?

Comment: Could do either, tricky part is the Id is generated so you need to pass it into a function if put in a standalone script.

Answer (score 2):

I like to disable the button and call a postback, this way the code behind still gets run after the button is disabled.

this is how i attach from code behind:

```
btnProcess.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; __doPostBack('btnProcess', ''); return false;")
```

Then re-enable the button in code behind:

```
btnProcess.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(':submit', this).click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me

```
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" CssClass="normalButton" 
Text="Button"  OnClick="Button_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" 
OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; setTimeout('enableButton()', 1500);" 
UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enableButton() {
document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

You can adjust the delay time in "setTimeout"

Comment: Why `getElementById('button')` ? It woulb be ***<%= button.ClientID %>*** ?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works if you are using asp.net validators:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function disableButton(sender,group)
{
    Page_ClientValidate(group);
    if (Page_IsValid)
    {
        sender.disabled = "disabled";
        __doPostBack(sender.name, '');
    }
}</script>
```

and change the button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSendMessage" Text="Send" OnClick="btnSendMessage_OnClick" OnClientClick="disableButton(this,'theValidationGroup')" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="theValidationGroup" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript.  in your `form` tag, `onsubmit="javascript:this.getElementById("submitButton").disabled='true';"`

Answer (score 0):

This works with a regular html button.

```
    <input id="Button1"
    onclick="this.disabled='true';" type="button"
    value="Submit" name="Button1"
    runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_Click">
```

The button is disabled until the postback is finished, preventing double clicking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function DisableButtons() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i in inputs) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "button" || inputs[i].type == "submit") {
            inputs[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = DisableButtons;
</script>
```