# The name 'ClientScript' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a behindcode javascript. it is to show a javascript dialog box.

however, it keep show this error

```
The name 'ClientScript' does not exist in the current context
```

This code was put inside masterpage. I had also use the exactly same code at other aspx file, and it work out fine apart from this..

here is my code:

```
   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "Order Placed Successfully.";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString()); string script = "alert('abc');";

    }
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try:

```
Page.ClientScript
```

instead to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I got "The name 'Page' does not exist in the current context", any ideas why?

Answer (score 8):

For cs file the sample is;

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "{some text for type}", "alert('{Text come to here}'); ", true);
```

for masterpage cs the sample is;

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "{some text for type}", "alert('{Text come to here}'); ", true);
```

Comment: Tnaks denize for the detail explanation

Answer (score 3):

On the master page try `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` instead. Watch out, the signature slightly differs from `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`.

- Documentation of the [ScriptManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)