# Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, clientscript

Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript' cannot be used as a method.

---

I am trying to Freeze a button upon click so the user won't double-click accidentally causing duplicates entity. Here is my code:

```
      private void FreezeButton()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') { ");

        sb.Append("var oldPage_IsValid = Page_IsValid; var oldPage_BlockSubmit = Page_BlockSubmit;");
        sb.Append("if (Page_ClientValidate('" + btnAdd.ValidationGroup + "') == false) {");
        sb.Append(" Page_IsValid = oldPage_IsValid; Page_BlockSubmit = oldPage_BlockSubmit; return false; }} ");

        sb.Append("this.value = 'Processing...';");
        sb.Append("this.disabled = true;");

        sb.Append(Page.ClientScript(btnAdd, null) + ";");
        sb.Append("return true;");

        string submitButton = sb.ToString();

        btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", submitButton);
    }
```

First I tried to use the Client without the **Page.ClientScript** and it gave me Error for: The name `'ClientScript'` does not exist in the current context

Then I looked at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808329/the-name-clientscript-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) question and found out that you could use it like Page.ClientScript but now I am getting the Error Non-invocable member

Comment: [It's a property, not a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.clientscript?view=netframework-4.7.2) - _"Gets a ClientScriptManager object used to manage, register, and add script to the page."_

Comment: @stuartd I see so is there another way of doing this? I need to be able to apply this effect to this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
  private void FreezeButton()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') { ");

        sb.Append("var oldPage_IsValid = Page_IsValid; var oldPage_BlockSubmit = Page_BlockSubmit;");
        sb.Append("if (Page_ClientValidate('" + btnAdd.ValidationGroup + "') == false) {");
        sb.Append(" Page_IsValid = oldPage_IsValid; Page_BlockSubmit = oldPage_BlockSubmit; return false; }} ");

        sb.Append("this.value = 'Processing...';");
        sb.Append("this.disabled = true;");

        sb.Append(Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnAdd, null) + ";");
        sb.Append("return true;");

        string submitButtonOnclickJs = sb.ToString();

        btnAddReceipt.Attributes.Add("onclick", submitButtonOnclickJs);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Page.ClientScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.clientscript?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a property, you cannot use it like a method. Probably you're looking for `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` to include script content into page body, which explained by another answer in the referenced question link.

Assumed you're handling `btnAdd` which is a server control with `FreezeButton` method event handling, you should replace the content to contain `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and JS function name to call client-side validation like example below:

```
protected void FreezeButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("function validate() { ")

    // script content here, skipped for brevity

    sb.Append("}");

    // use RegisterClientScriptBlock to attach script content into <script> tag inside page body
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Example", sb.ToString(), true);

    // handle client-side event click if the button is a server control
    btnAdd.OnClientClick = "validate()";
}
```

Then, handle server-side click event of `btnAdd` like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="FreezeButton" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and because of the hint I got from your answer I was able to find the solution.