# ASP.net Button disable for seconds and run server code at the same time

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. I have an asp.net button with a click event (that runs some server side code). I want to change the button, so that when clicked, it turn grey and disabled for 3 seconds, but it will also run server code at the same time. But, the button will change color if it postback.

Thanks for guidance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189593/disable-asp-net-button-after-click-to-prevent-double-clicking

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery  `setTimeout` to disable button for 3 second like this.

```
$('#YourButtonID').click(function(){
    var yourBtn = $(this);
    yourBtn.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        yourBtn.prop('disabled', false);
    }, 3000);
});
```

To get ID  :

```
$("#<%=YourButtonID.ClientID%>")
```

Or you can use class .