# How to add span tag to button in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to add spinner to the button. I searched and I found the simplest way is describe by Flion on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793367/how-to-add-a-spinner-icon-to-button-when-its-in-the-loading-state). I dont know how add the suggested button code to my asp.net button.

Suggested code is

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></span> Loading..</button>
```

and my code is

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the suggested code as it is. You just need to use the `runat="server"` to access that html button at code behind. Apart from this you also need to setup the `onclick` event like this

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" id="LoginButton">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></span>Loading..
</button>
```

Comment: I got the following error
Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'LoginButton', but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton).

Comment: try cleaning the solution and rebuild it. Make sure there should not be two controls with same id `LoginButton`

Answer (score 1):

So in asp.net, the simple solution at least for now is

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="this.value='Please wait...';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

`<button id="btn" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1-Click">
    <span>Click</span></button>`

try using this code if it helps...

**Tell me if it helps...**

Comment: Thanks, that helped but ideally I am looking for this effect http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewDryga/zcX4h/1/

At the moment I am using asp.net with bootstrap plugin. Any suggestion?

Comment: I added the css part to the end of Bootstrap.css, javascript part in the head of the page under <script> </script> tag but it is not working