# Bootstrap - Modal dialog avoid duplicate entry and empty on load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am having a web app using bootstrap 3, datatables, js and php.

I am facing two issues:

a) When i press SAVE button on modal, it sometimes taking more seconds to load the code. This has a result, that users press again SAVE button. The result is that the app is getting duclicate answer(row in the database).

b) When modal is load, user can see for 1 second data from previous open row.

I want to fix this two issues.

I am posting a part of the modal and js. As my modal has 15 input/select fields.

My html code(.php) of the page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="update_appointment" tabindex="-4" role="dialog" aria-label="UpdateAppointmentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-customer" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">View Appointment</h5>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" id="UpdateAppointmentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row" id="UpdateAppointmentFormdiv">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="upd_app_date" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Date:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <input id="upd_app_date" name="app_date" type="text" class="form-control date"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="upd_work_id" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Work:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 form-group">
                                    <select id="upd_work_id" name="work_id" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="upd_app_price" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Price:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <input id="upd_app_price" name="app_price" type="text" class="form-control price" value=""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="upd_app_paid_to" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Paid To:</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                                    <select id="upd_app_paid_to" name="app_paid_to" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                        <option value="0">Bill</option>
                                        <option value="1">John</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="UpdateAppointmentFormloader" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
                            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js code of the modal submit button:

```
$('#UpdateAppointmentForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    upd_app_date = $('#upd_app_date').val();
    if (isValidDate(upd_app_date) === false) {
        alert("Appointment date is not valid.");
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#upd_work_id').val() != "") {
        upd_work = $('#upd_work_id option:selected').html();
    } else {
        upd_work = "";
    }
    if ($('#upd_app_paid_to').val() != "") {
        upd_app_paid_to = $('#upd_app_paid_to option:selected').html();
    } else {
        upd_app_paid_to = "";
    }
    
    html  = '<td>' + $('#upd_app_date').val() + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + upd_work + '</td>';
    html += '<td class="text-right">' + $('#upd_app_price').val() + '</td>';
    html += '<td class="text-center">' + upd_app_paid_to + '</td>'; 
    html += '<td class=" text-center">';
    html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm same_button_td" onclick="viewAppoitment(\'' + $('#upd_app_id').val() + '\')"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm same_button_td" onclick="editAppoitment(\'' + $('#upd_app_id').val() + '\', $(this))"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>';
    
    app_paid_to = $('#upd_app_paid_to').val();
    if (app_paid_to != "") {
        if (price_paid.length == 0) {
            alert("Price Paid cannot be blank.");
            return false;
        }
        if (payment_id == "") {
            alert("Select Payment");
            return false;
        }
        if (receipt_id == "") {
            alert("Select Receipt");
            return false;
        }
    }
    var form_data = $("#UpdateAppointmentForm").serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
    $('#UpdateAppointmentFormdiv').hide();
    $('#UpdateAppointmentFormloader').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/customer.php?action=UpdateAppointment",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.success == true) {
                $ele.parent().parent().html(html);
                html = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">' + result.message + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
                $('#appalertmsg').html(html);
                $('#appalert').slideDown();
                $('#UpdateAppointmentForm')[0].reset();
                $('#UpdateAppointmentFormdiv').show();
                $('#UpdateAppointmentFormloader').hide();
                $('#update_appointment').modal('hide');
            } else {
                html = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">' + result.message + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
                $('#appalertmsg').html(html);
                $('#appalert').slideDown();
                $('#UpdateAppointmentFormdiv').show();
                $('#UpdateAppointmentFormloader').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Solution for my A problem.
If i put after `event.preventDefault();` this lines:

```
    $('#UpdateAppointmentFormdiv').hide();
    $('#UpdateAppointmentFormloader').show();
```

will it fix my issue.

Solution for my B problem.
I tried to use the following:

```
$('#update_appointment').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#upd_app_date').val('');
    $('#upd_work_id').val('');
    $('#upd_app_price').val('');
    $('#upd_app_paid_to').val('');
});
```

but with no success. Maybe i am having a small typo error in my code.

Comment: `hidden.bs.modal` event handler gets called or not ?

Comment: @Swati With all my knowledge, i will say yes. I tested the code in a more simple modal with only one input field.

Comment: Then it should work . Alternative way would be adding `$("#UpdateAppointmentForm").find("input,select").val("")`after `var form_data = $("#UpdateAppointmentForm").serialize();` . But , your modal form id is `UpdateMemoAppointmentForm` ?

Comment: @Swati My mistake, correct the code with MEMO. I have two modals, update and update_memo and mix the code here. Now, i update it to correct one. Before the ajax to empty the val? About the duplicate entry that sometimes it happening? Press SAVE and i can press again. This is adding twice the same data in the database.

Comment: About my previous comment you can add that line  because you are already getting values of inputs i.e  : `var form_data = $("#UpdateAppointmentForm").serialize();` or add that thing inside success function of ajax and for second issue just disable that button when user click on it first time and enable it inside success function of ajax.

Comment: @Swati I think the delay of the server is making this error. If i disable the button and it is taking long time, should i put something? If i close the modal, how can i avoid duplicate? It is a web app, server is at home and user is at office.

Comment: You can add some `loading...` gif till ajax request is complete . Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684722/show-loading-image-while-ajax-is-performed) should helped.

Comment: @Swati I think i have this in here in my code `$('#UpdateAppointmentFormloader').show();`

Comment: I am not able to understand can you elaborate ?

Comment: @Swati For `loading...` gif,i am having before ajax call `    $('#UpdateAppointmentFormdiv').hide();` and `$('#UpdateAppointmentFormloader').show();`. I will add an id on html `id=btnsubmit` and add in js on 3rd line `$('#btnsubmit').disabled();` My issue with the button is giving you the sense that you didn't press it. You press it but you see in the screen nothing is happening so you are pressing it again and adding in the table two lines.

Comment: I see so you can show loading button something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793367/how-to-add-a-spinner-icon-to-button-when-its-in-the-loading-state)

Comment: @Swati Simple add disable and fix the issue