# How to disable submit button after click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im currently working on an extension where I currently have a submit button and input. When a user is clicking on the submit button, the user should not be able to click on the submit button anymore and should be disabled and if the user has already entered a user ID then it should also not be able to click on submit again.

How can I be able to disable the submit button when a user has clicked it or has already clicked it before using my code below?

**popup.js**

```
function get_discord_id(callback) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["discord_id"], (result) => {
        callback(result.discord_id);
    });
}

function set_discord_id(discord_id) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ discord_id: discord_id }, () => {});
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    // console.log(`Testing: ${input.placeholder}`)
    // check if discord ID is already stored
    get_discord_id((discord_id) => {
        console.log(`Console test:`);
        if (discord_id != null) {
            let input = document.getElementById("discord-id-input");
            input.value = "";
            input.placeholder = discord_id;
        }
    });

    document.getElementById("discord-id-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let input = document.getElementById("discord-id-input");
        let value = input.value;
        input.value = "";
        input.placeholder = value;

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ discord_id: value }, function(response) {
            // console.log(response.discord_id);
        });

        set_discord_id(value);
        e.target.disabled = "true";
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="../js/popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="form-control mt10">
            <input type="text" id="discord-id-input" name="discord-id-input" placeholder="Discord ID">
            <button id="discord-id-button" type="submit" class="submit"></button>
            <a class="help-text">ENTER DISCORD USER ID AND SUBMIT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#discord-id-button {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #251431;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#discord-id-button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 6px #251431;
}

#discord-id-input {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px 0 #251431;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

body {
    background-image: url('../images/bg2.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 5px 15px 30px 15px;
    width: 500px;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.form-control {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

select,
input {
    background: #582e79;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px #582e79;
    color: #999;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 135px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}

.mt10 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.submit {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("../images/arrow.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    height: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 135px;
    outline: none;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.help-text {
    position: fixed;
    color: #FFFF;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #999;
    margin-top: 190px;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+disable+submit+button+after+click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTML button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

Comment: Hello Robert, the question did tell me whats the syntax to use it but I do not know where to place it and to also check if it already has a value set

Comment: Then include that information in your question.

Comment: I did mention that, that I wonder how I can do that? I will include that it should be in my code :)

Comment: you have added `onclick="this.disabled=true"` in html. did you tried to wrap true` inside of single quote like onclick="this.disabled='true'"

Comment: I also just tested with and without the single quotes aswell as tried to do without the function aswell. Same result :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable submit button once it has been clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
document.getElementById('button').disabled="true";
```

Comment: Hello! hmm where should I place that?

Comment: Add an submit event listner to form and add this inside it

Comment: But I do already have done, dont I?

Comment: I have created a fiddle. Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/gc3v45dx/

Comment: you can also achieve by using `onclick="this.disabled='true'"`

Comment: remember using single quote around `true`

Comment: Just tested your example with my code and it seems like it does not set it to disable

Comment: Well it works fine on my device.

Comment: See the video here :) https://gyazo.com/cf71d0d937b2d8b7dbc4f529ac9f2490 - and I used your both examples as well.

Comment: add screenshot of your code too

Comment: I have edited the code in the thread -> See the popup.js :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want some extra styling for your disabled button you could do this:

- add two classes to your html button: enabled and disabled. Then, on click, replace the "disabled" class with the class "enabled" and remove event listener.

If you just want to disable it, ignore the part with the classes and just disable it on click.

Simple fiddle:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const classes = button.classList;

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick)


function handleClick() {
  //classes.replace('enabled', 'disabled');
  button.disabled = true;
  button.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<button class="enabled"> submit</button>
```