# disable submit button once it has been clicked but stuck in sending

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask, form-submit

There is a similar question here:[How to disable submit button once it has been clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked)

But no answer works for me.

if I use:

```
onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…'; "
```

code:

```
{{ comment_form.submit(class_="btn btn-primary",onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…'; ") }}
```

There will still be duplicated submits ,the submit has not been disabled

if I use:

```
onClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…';"
```

code:

```
    {{comment_form.submit(class_="btn btn-primary",onClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…';") }}
  </div>
```

It will stuck at 'Sending...',and no submit happen.

Comment: You should update your code and leave inline javascript, the referenced question has 13yo

Comment: You need to add a delay when setting disabled so the form will submit.

Comment: const btn = this; window.setTimeout(()=>btn.disabled = true, 1);

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for your reply ,can you give me an example ,how to add a depay inline ,thanks.

Comment: @epascarello can you write it as an answer I want to check it ,it works ,thanks!