# Disable button on submit click in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

On submit button i want to disable the button so user does not click more than once. im using jquery for that but its not working, my code is

```
setTimeout($('#btn').attr("disabled", true), 1);
return true;
```

button get disabled but my controller does not call. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: why using `setTimeout` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}, 1);
```

Comment: my controller code is not calling. its like when it disable the button the request is stopped?

Comment: I've found that disabling a button in the click event prevents the form being submitted in some versions of IE. I've posted a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294041/disable-the-button-after-clicking-the-button-once/4218820#4218820

Answer (score 6):

I don't see much reason to use timeout, I'd just go with

```
$('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
return true;
```

or more precisely,

```
$('#btn').click( function (e) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

is all you need.

And being a bit wicked and esoteric :P

```
return !!$('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and that, was just for fun. Don't do it in your code! :)

**Edit**: with a recent version of jQuery, you can make it

```
$('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout($('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled),1);
$("#btn").removeAttr('disabled', disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$("#loginButton").click(function (e) {
        var btn = $(this).clone();
        btn.prop("disabled", true)
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after(btn);
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
setTimeout($('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled'), 1);
return true;
```

Comment: You're passing the jQuery object to `setTimeout`, IMO, it is not a callable, nor a string to `eval` :)