# Clarification on temporarily disabling a submit button for a number seconds, then re-enable it?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

This is similiar to another question that was asked however the form will not submit.

Basically what I am trying achieve here is that once the user clicks the "submit" btn , the btn is disabled until the page is re-directed, so as to avoid the user clicking the submit btn several times.

The page that the user is re-directed to will not display the information from the form.
This did function correctly before I introduced the disable and enable functions.

The code provided does disable the btn and even changes the text to "submitting" but does not not re-direct to the summary page, and even when I navigate to the summary page via a tab the information is not there.
Any help is most appreciated...

form code........

```
  <div class="portlet-body form">
        <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
        @using (Html.BeginForm("RequestAppointment", "Appointment", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id= "apptReqForm" }))
        {


            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false, string.Empty, new { @class = "alert alert-error" })

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Healthcare Professional</label>
                <div class="controls">         
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RequestedUserID, Model.Hcps, string.Empty)

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RequestedDateTime)</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append" id="ui_date_picker_trigger">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.RequestedDateTime)
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedTime, "Time")</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div id="timeSlotID" data-request-url="@Url.Action("LoadTimeslots")">
                        <select id="SelectedTime" name="SelectedTime"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalNotes)</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AdditionalNotes, new { @class = "span6 m-wrap", rows = 3 })
                    <span class="help-block m-wrap">In the event the selected time you have chosen is not available, please state above if your booking time is flexible.</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class= "btn blue" id="submit" onclick="disable();"><i class="icon-ok"></i>Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="location.href='RequestedAppointments'">Cancel</button>

            </div>
        }
    </div>

   <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class= "btn blue" id="submit" onclick="disable();"><i class="icon-ok"></i>Submit</button>

  <script>

function disable() {
    x = document.getElementById("submit");
    x.disabled = true;
    x.textContent = "Submitting...";
    document.getElementById("apptReqForm").submit();
    setTimeout(enable, 5000);
}

function enable() {
    x = document.getElementById("submit");
    x.disabled = false;
    x.textContent = " Submit";
}
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your script to do the following:

```
function disable() {
    x = document.getElementById("submit");
    x.form.submit();
    x.disabled = true;
    x.textContent = "Submitting...";
    setTimeout(enable, 5000);
}

function enable() {
    x = document.getElementById("submit");
    x.disabled = false;
    x.textContent = " Submit";
}
```

The very fact of disabling the button may, however, be causing the postback to fail.

Try looking at this solution (it uses jQuery)
[Disable button after clicking once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4218820/2311892)

Comment: Do you mean ........  document.getElementById("<insert your form id here">).onsubmit();

Comment: No... onsubmit is the event handler, submit is the method. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: I'm afraid all I get after making those changes is the btn disabled with the textContent of the btn changed to "submitting" and page is not making any attempt to re-direct...thanks anyway

Comment: This may be similar to the issue that ASP.NET had with disabled buttons not triggering a postback, but it is hard for me to test.

Answer (score 0):

Would you believe 3 simple line's...

Change the id of the button from "submit", to anything else as this confuse's Visual Studio

```
 id="submitreq"
```

and then added the following to the submitHandler function..

```
  var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitreq");
                submitButton.disabled = true;
                submitButton.textContent = "Submitting...";

                form.submit();
```